# Are missing parameters in Odata entity type valid?

Tags: properties, odata

I have been studying an OData service and I have noticed that even requesting full responses there are some entity types where not all of the properties defined in the entity type metadata are returned. I cant find anything in the OData spec saying whether this is legal or not. The closest I found was for an entity type they have the open type attribute which allows for dynamic adding of properties, but since there is nothing allowing dynamic removal I was assuming this was not legal.

Is this practice legal from the point of view of the OData spec?

Example Odata

```
<EntityType Name="Account">
    <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="ServiceEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
</EntityType>
```

Example Response

```
{
  "Status: "Ok"
}
```

In this example the ServiceEnabled Property is not returned from the server.

Comment: If you query an entity or a collection of entity, all properties should be returned from service, no matter whether it is declared or dynamic property. Except that you use the $select to return the certain properties that you set on select clause. So, Your situation is strange. Would you please share use more context? for example some codes? Thanks.

Comment: Certain properties in the entity are tagged with a custom term which says whether they are required or not, the properties that are not tagged as required are not returned or even implemented in some cases but the schema still lists them.